# ListView scrollbar not displayed after ListView.setBackgroundDrawable(null)

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a listView with a background, scrollbar is showing as wanted.
But when I rewove the background with ListView.setBackgroundDrawable(null), the scrollbar does not show anymore.
Is this the normal behavior ?
How to make it visible again ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set ListView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000) instead of ListView.setBackgroundDrawable(null).

Answer (score 0):

To make it visible again, use setBackgroundDrawable() again not passing null.

Comment: I do not want to have any background on my ListView again. But setting mListView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Ah yes I was going to say try setBackgroundColor as well ... glad it worked :)